# Stats From a Datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq

Using VB .NET, I am wondering about the best way to get some statistical data out of a Datatable.  I would rather not hit the database with another query, but just look through the datatable I already have.

So, Linq must be the answer?

I have a datatable (dtable) containing two columns: tech_id and colour.  From this, I would like a new datatable containing three columns: tech_id, colour, and count.  Of course, I'm trying to figure out how many times each "tech_id" used each distinct "colour".  Something like:

```
tech_id     colour     count
------------------------------
JM          brown      18
JM          purple     10
JM          green      3
PB          brown      51
PB          grey       8
TD          brown      4
TD          pink       67
TD          grey       41
```

My best attempt with Linq is not at all correct, but is pasted below to show how far I've gotten:

```
Dim ColourCounts = From p In PGWorkingDataTable.AsEnumerable() _
         Group p By p.Field(Of String)("colour") Into Count() _
         Select tech_id, colour, ColourCount = Count

Dim colourStatsTable As DataTable = ColourCounts.CopyToDataTable()
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out

[How can I use LINQ to summarize this data--number of relationships grouped by the count of those relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604369/how-can-i-use-linq-to-summarize-this-data-number-of-relationships-grouped-by-the)

Comment: This is good info, but I'm still a little confused as to how to use it properly.  I think my linq skills need work in general.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, no less.

Comment: No Problem. I agree that linq is a peculiar beast that takes some time to get your head around. I'm still far from there myself.